# html table rows height issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so I made that table which I want it too look like a gradebook but I cant edit the row heights.

In the picture below I drew a line around the rows I want their size to be decrease so they can look different than the student's rows.

[image: Current Table]

and heres the HTML

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:white;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th rowspan="4">Student</th>
   <th>Assignment</th>
   <td>Assignment 1</td>
   <td>Assignment 2</td>
   <td>Assignment 3</td>
   <td>Assignment 4</td>

  </tr>
    <div>
  <tr>
   <th>Category:</th>
   <td>Category 1</td>
   <td>Category 2</td>
   <td>Category 3</td>
   <td>Category 4</td>
  </tr></div>
  <tr>
   <th>Due:</th>
   <td>Due 1</td>
   <td>Due 2</td>
   <td>Due 3</td>
   <td>Due 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Points:</th>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Moemen Waleed</td>
   <td>90% A-</td>
   <td>Moemen 1</td>
   <td>Moemen 2</td>
   <td>Moemen 3</td>
   <td>Moemen 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Mazen Waleed</td>
   <td>93% A</td>
   <td>Mazen 1</td>
   <td>Mazen 2</td>
   <td>Mazen 3</td>
   <td>Mazen 4</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try `line-height`?

Comment: perhaps you should add your css too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to your hmtl:

```
<style>
  tr:nth-child(-n+4){
     line-height: 10px;
     min-height: 10px;
     height: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

This styles all first four rows in the table.
Here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbx8xh1a/4/

Comment: I saw the jsfiddle and it seems it works fine but somehow it doesnt work here.

Comment: wait I think the problem is from the grid div's let me post all my div cols

Comment: The table is inside <div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive"> which is inside ............ <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left: -15px;!important">
      <div class="profile-sidebar">

Comment: I think you have many tables. you have to add class for your table. check this https://jsfiddle.net/Lbx8xh1a/5/

Comment: The reason I cant share the whole code cuz its 3 pages including each others.

Comment: Okay! I hope you will find better design

Answer (score 0):

You can add `line-height` to that `<tr>` tags.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:white;">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="line-height: 6px;">
                <th rowspan="4">Student</th>
                <th>Assignment</th>
                <td>Assignment 1</td>
                <td>Assignment 2</td>
                <td>Assignment 3</td>
                <td>Assignment 4</td>
    
            </tr>
        <div>
            <tr style="line-height: 6px;">
                <th>Category:</th>
                <td>Category 1</td>
                <td>Category 2</td>
                <td>Category 3</td>
                <td>Category 4</td>
            </tr></div>
            <tr style="line-height: 6px;">
                <th>Due:</th>
                <td>Due 1</td>
                <td>Due 2</td>
                <td>Due 3</td>
                <td>Due 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="line-height: 6px;">
                <th>Points:</th>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Moemen Waleed</td>
                <td>90% A-</td>
                <td>Moemen 1</td>
                <td>Moemen 2</td>
                <td>Moemen 3</td>
                <td>Moemen 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mazen Waleed</td>
                <td>93% A</td>
                <td>Mazen 1</td>
                <td>Mazen 2</td>
                <td>Mazen 3</td>
                <td>Mazen 4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```